# Arbitrary number of lists within a list java

Tags: java

Is there a way I can add an arbitrary number of lists within a list in java?

For example:

```
List<List<T>, List<T>, List<T>>
```

I know this is incorrect syntax, but I want to do something like that.

Comment: Do you mean `List<List<List<...>>>`?

Comment: For arbitrarily nested lists of lists of lists etc. you could just drop the java-generics-stuff: `List nestesList = new ArrayList();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`List<List<T>>` will hold any number of `List<T>`. For example:

```
List<List<T>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<T>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // 10 is arbitrary here; just an example
    listOfLists.add(new ArrayList<T>());
}
```

Without being more information about use cases or why you'd want to do this, I can't be more specific.

Comment: you do not have to use new ArrayList<List<T>>();  you can use <> operator e.g. List<List<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
}

Answer (score 1):

In case you meant arbitrarily nested lists of lists of lists of lists... you might want to use a tree structure instead, something like this:

```
class Tree<T> {
    T element;
    List<Tree<T>> children;
}
```

Or this, if you want to separate intermediate layers and values:

```
interface Tree<T> { 
}

class TreeNode<T> implements Tree<T> {
    List<Tree<T>> children;
}

class TreeLeaf<T> implements Tree<T> {
    T element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have lists `list1`, `list2`, ..., `listN`, there are multiple ways you could go about this:

**Create your own class for a n-tuple:**
This methodology will allow you to limit your tuple to a specific size, without having to re-implement the methods of the `Collection` or `List` classes.

```
public class ThreeTuple<A, B, C> {
    private final A first;
    private final B second;
    private final C third;

    public ThreeTuple(A first, B second, C third) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
        this.third = third;
    }

    public A getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public B getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public C getThird() {
        return third;
    }
}

public class OtherClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreeTuple(list1, list2, list3);
    }
}
```

**Add n lists to a list:**
This methodology is definitely the simplest, but does not bound the list.

```
List<List<T>> lists = new ArrayList<T>();
lists.add(list1);
lists.add(list2);
lists.add(list3);
```